# Sed regex to find-replace version numbers

Tags: regex, sed

I'm new to sed, trying to write a script to find/replace text in a file. The file (test.txt) looks like this;

```
   hello_world (1.2.0.123)
```

and I'm finding that this script (which I inherited):

```
sed -i 's/\(^\s*hello_world \)(.*)/\1hello_world (1.2.0.456)/' test.txt
```

is leading to;

```
   hello_world hello_world (1.2.0.456)
```

when I need it to be

```
   hello_world (1.2.0.456)
```

I'm not sure how to make the first part match only the parentheses, any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT

- The whitespace before the hello_world is important
- The sed line is being auto-generated using variables etc. I'm looking for a way to make this regex work without changing that. The variables I have to play with are

  - variable1: hello_world
  - variable2: hello_world (1.2.0.456)

(hopefully it's obvious where these variables sat within the sed expression)

EDIT

I got this sorted in the end, answer below if anyone else is interested.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make it clear what you're looking for.  It seems from the edit that you cannot change the `sed` expression?

Comment: I could change the sed expression, but it was of the format:

(..regex..)variable1(..regex..)variable2(..regex..) 

and I wanted a solution that wouldn't involve changing the variables (which are indicated as v1 and v2 above) - but I got it sorted in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```
 sed -i 's/\(^\s*\)phoenix_utils (.*)/\1phoenix_utils (1.0.0.28583)/' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e 's/^\([[:blank:]]*hello_world \).*/\1(1.0.0.28583)/' YourFile
```

`\1` is the content of first `( )` so \1Helloworld write it twice in your sample

be carefull with escape content depending of -e or not (behavior change and non GNU sed often need to escape `(`for grouping pattern)